# TreeView with EnableViewState=False cannot be selected

Tags: treeview, viewstate

I have a large TreeView that takes lots of ViewState. I can easily refresh the treeview on load, but if I click on a node in the tree, the onselectednode_changed event doesn't get fired because the tree is empty when the browser does a postback. Is there any way around this that will get the onselected event to fire?

Answer (score 0):

Note 100% sure a tree view will work without viewstate. What is pretty definite is that if you have viewstate turned off, you will need to re-render it on every postback. No checking for IsPostBack and skipping that step.

-A